# Use of 'or' and inversion in questions: "Is it due to eating unhealthy food or it is due to not playing sport?"

Tags: questions, inversion, coordination

If someone has a health problem and I would like to ask him/her what the cause of the problem is, two questions are in my mind:

1. Is it due to eating unhealthy food?
2. Is it due to not playing sport?

Now I need to use the word *or* or something like that to ask the two questions at the same time. How can I do it to sound like a native speaker? And which of the following is correct?

1. Is it due to eating unhealthy food *or* not playing sport?
2. Is it due to eating unhealthy food *or* **is it** due to not playing sport?
3. Is it due to eating unhealthy food *or* **it is** due to not playing sport?

Thank you,

Comment: I'm not a native speaker, but I think that the third one is wrong and that the first one needs an additional *to*: «...or not *to* playing any sports?».

Comment: Moreover the second alternative sounds unnecessarily repetitive with the addition of the second "is it".

Comment: You could just ask the questions sequentially, as with your first 1 & 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second option

> Is it due to eating unhealthy food or is it due to not playing sport?

is correct and clearest, but not the most common usage.

The first option

> Is it due to eating unhealthy food or not playing sport?

is the most common usage but it also logically allows a yes/no answer which (I'm assuming) you don't want.

The third option is incorrect (in UK English).

Comment: If my second option is not the most common usage and the first option allow a yes/no answer. Would you suggest a clear and most common phrase that has the same meaning, Please?

Comment: You can use either first or second options, I say the second is not the most common but it is the most correct. The first option is what people would usually expect you to use and in 99.9% of cases would give the answer you expect.